# How to draw connectors for venn diagram chart in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, angular, charts, highcharts, venn-diagram

I was trying to achieve the below chart. However, there are two problems I am facing. I am able to create most of the charts. Here is the link to [Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/not_a_genius/4bzus1g3/268/).

1. Here I was able to get the data labels as shown in the image but I don't want to use the function. If it is possible, please tell me how?
2. Second is the connecting lines between data labels and charts. This I was able to achieve even with any function. There is something called connector shape for pie chart in which we have one of the options as **crookedLine**. The connector lines in the below image look like that. Please help me, even with function.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'venn',
    marginLeft: 350,
    events: {
      load: drawDataLabel
    }
  },
  title: {
    text: 'EXTERNAL IP MALWARE INFECTION SUMMARY'
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: '<span><b>85%</b> 85 IPS NOT INFETCED<span>',
    useHTML: true,
    style: {
      color: '#34c52d',
      fontWeight: 400,
      padding: '2px 20px',
      border: '2px solid #F2F2F2'
    }
  },
  exporting: {
    enabled: false
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  plotOptions: {
    venn: {
      borderColor: 'transparent'
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    enabled: false
  },
  series: [{
    type: 'venn',
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: false,
      align: 'left'
    },
    data: [{
        sets: ['A'],
        name: "<div style='width:36vw; padding:0.3em; border: 2px solid #F2F2F2'>15 % IPs WITH MALWRAE INFECTION</div>",
        value: 10,
        color: '#ffb81c',
        dataLabels: {
          //x: series.dataLabel.x,
          x: 0,
          y: -70,
          color: '#FFB81C',
          //borderColor: '#F2F2F2',
          //borderWidth: 2,
          useHTML: true,
          style: {
            //width: 200,
            textOutline: 'none'
          }
        }
      }, {
        sets: ['B'],
        name: "<div style='width:36vw; padding:0.3em; border: 2px solid #F2F2F2'>5% 5 INFECTED WITH CNCs</div>",
        value: 5,
        color: '#ff8319',
        dataLabels: {
          //x: 'point.x',
          //x: -363,
          y: 0,
          color: '#FF8319',
          //borderColor: '#F2F2F2',
          //borderWidth: 2,
          useHTML: true,
          style: {
            //width: 200,
            textOutline: 'none'
          }
        }
      }, {
        sets: ['C'],
        value: 2,
        name: "<div style='width:36vw;  padding:0.3em; border: 2px solid #F2F2F2'>3% 3 IPs BLACKLISTED</div>",
        color: '#e30000',
        dataLabels: {
          //x: 'point.x',
          //x: -301,
          y: 70,
          color: '#e30000',
          //borderColor: '#F2F2F2',
          //borderWidth: 2,
          useHTML: true,
          style: {
            //width: 200,
            textOutline: 'none'
          }
        }
      },
      {
        sets: ['A', 'B'],
        value: 4.999,
        name: ' ',
        color: '#FF8319'
      },
      {
        sets: ['B', 'C'],
        value: 1.999,
        name: ' ',
        color: '#e30000'
      }
    ]
  }]
});

function drawDataLabel() {
  var points = this.series[0].points,
    point1R = points[0].shapeArgs.r;


  this.renderer.label('15 % IPs WITH MALWRAE INFECTION', 0, 150, 'rect', points[0].plotX + this.plotLeft, points[0].plotY + this.plotTop)
    .css({
      color: '#FFB81C'
    })
    .attr({
      width: 210,
      fill: '#FFFFFF',
      'stroke-width': 2,
      stroke: '#F2F2F2',
      padding: 5,
      fontWeight: 400,
      zIndex: 6
    })
    .add();

  this.renderer.label('5% 5 INFECTED WITH CNCs', 0, 270, 'rect', points[1].plotX + this.plotLeft, points[1].plotY + this.plotTop)
    .css({
      color: '#FF8319'
    })
    .attr({
      width: 210,
      fill: '#FFFFFF',
      'stroke-width': 2,
      stroke: '#F2F2F2',
      padding: 5,
      fontWeight: '400',
      zIndex: 6
    })
    .add();

  this.renderer.label('3% 3 IPs BLACKLISTED', 0, 210, 'rect', points[2].plotX + this.plotLeft, points[2].plotY + this.plotTop)
    .css({
      color: '#E30000'
    })
    .attr({
      width: 210,
      fill: '#FFFFFF',
      'stroke-width': 2,
      stroke: '#F2F2F2',
      padding: 5,
      fontWeight: '400',
      zIndex: 6
    })
    .add();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/venn.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>
</figure>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is provided in the comment by @ppotaczek.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'venn',
    marginLeft: 350,
    events: {
      load: drawDataLabel
    }
  },
  title: {
    text: 'EXTERNAL IP MALWARE INFECTION SUMMARY'
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: '<span><b>85%</b> 85 IPS NOT INFETCED<span>',
    useHTML: true,
    style: {
      color: '#34c52d',
      fontWeight: 400,
      padding: '2px 20px',
      border: '2px solid #F2F2F2'
    }
  },
  exporting: {
    enabled: false
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  plotOptions: {
    venn: {
      borderColor: 'transparent'
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    enabled: false
  },
  series: [{
    type: 'venn',
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: false,
      align: 'left'
    },
    data: [{
        sets: ['A'],
        name: "<div style='width:36vw; padding:0.3em; border: 2px solid #F2F2F2'>15 % IPs WITH MALWRAE INFECTION</div>",
        value: 10,
        color: '#ffb81c',
        dataLabels: {
          //x: series.dataLabel.x,
          x: 0,
          y: -70,
          color: '#FFB81C',
          //borderColor: '#F2F2F2',
          //borderWidth: 2,
          useHTML: true,
          style: {
            //width: 200,
            textOutline: 'none'
          }
        }
      }, {
        sets: ['B'],
        name: "<div style='width:36vw; padding:0.3em; border: 2px solid #F2F2F2'>5% 5 INFECTED WITH CNCs</div>",
        value: 5,
        color: '#ff8319',
        dataLabels: {
          //x: 'point.x',
          //x: -363,
          y: 0,
          color: '#FF8319',
          //borderColor: '#F2F2F2',
          //borderWidth: 2,
          useHTML: true,
          style: {
            //width: 200,
            textOutline: 'none'
          }
        }
      }, {
        sets: ['C'],
        value: 2,
        name: "<div style='width:36vw;  padding:0.3em; border: 2px solid #F2F2F2'>3% 3 IPs BLACKLISTED</div>",
        color: '#e30000',
        dataLabels: {
          //x: 'point.x',
          //x: -301,
          y: 70,
          color: '#e30000',
          //borderColor: '#F2F2F2',
          //borderWidth: 2,
          useHTML: true,
          style: {
            //width: 200,
            textOutline: 'none'
          }
        }
      },
      {
        sets: ['A', 'B'],
        value: 4.999,
        name: ' ',
        color: '#FF8319'
      },
      {
        sets: ['B', 'C'],
        value: 1.999,
        name: ' ',
        color: '#e30000'
      }
    ]
  }]
});

function drawDataLabel() {
  var points = this.series[0].points,
    point1R = points[0].shapeArgs.r;
    var data = this.series[0].data;
  var boxX = 5;
  var baseBoxY = 50;
  var baseLabelValueSvg = 20;

    console.clear();
    console.log(this.plotX, this.plotY, this.plotRight, this.plotLeft, this.plotTop);
  this.renderer.label('15 % IPs WITH MALWRAE INFECTION', boxX, (this.yAxis[0].right + (baseLabelValueSvg + (2.5 * baseBoxY))), 'rect', data[0].plotX, data[0].plotY, true)
    .css({
      color: '#FFB81C'
    })
    .attr({
      width: 210,
      fill: '#FFFFFF',
      'stroke-width': 2,
      stroke: '#F2F2F2',
      padding: 5,
      fontWeight: 400,
      zIndex: 6
    })
    .add();

  this.renderer.path(['M', 210, (this.yAxis[0].right + (baseLabelValueSvg + (2.5 * baseBoxY)))+12, 'L', this.plotLeft, (this.yAxis[0].right + (baseLabelValueSvg + (2.5 * baseBoxY)))+12, 420, 200]).attr({
    'stroke-width': 2,
    stroke: '#FFB81C'
  }).add();


  this.renderer.label('5% 5 INFECTED WITH CNCs',boxX, (this.yAxis[0].right + (baseLabelValueSvg + (5.1 * baseBoxY))), 'rect', data[1].plotX, data[1].plotY, true)
    .css({
      color: '#FF8319'
    })
    .attr({
      width: 210,
      fill: '#FFFFFF',
      'stroke-width': 2,
      stroke: '#F2F2F2',
      padding: 5,
      fontWeight: '400',
      zIndex: 6
    })
    .add();

  this.renderer.path(['M', 210, (this.yAxis[0].right + (baseLabelValueSvg + (5.1 * baseBoxY)))+12, 'L', this.plotLeft, (this.yAxis[0].right + (baseLabelValueSvg + (5.1 * baseBoxY)))+12, 420, 250]).attr({
    'stroke-width': 2,
    stroke: '#FF8319'
  }).add();


  this.renderer.label('3% 3 IPs BLACKLISTED', boxX, (this.yAxis[0].right + (baseLabelValueSvg + (3.8 * baseBoxY))), 'rect', data[2].plotX, data[2].plotY, true)
    .css({
      color: '#E30000'
    })
    .attr({
      width: 210,
      fill: '#FFFFFF',
      'stroke-width': 2,
      stroke: '#F2F2F2',
      padding: 5,
      fontWeight: '400',
      zIndex: 6
    })
    .add();

  this.renderer.path(['M', 210, (this.yAxis[0].right + (baseLabelValueSvg + (3.8 * baseBoxY)))+12, 'L', 420, (this.yAxis[0].right + (baseLabelValueSvg + (3.8 * baseBoxY)))+12]).attr({
    'stroke-width': 2,
    stroke: '#E30000'
  }).add();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/venn.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>
</figure>
```

Anyone searching for an answer. Here is the [final version](https://jsfiddle.net/not_a_genius/4bzus1g3/314/) based on [this](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4e2Lvnty)